# How to redraw arrow diagrams from Word

Tags: chemistry

I want to start using`LaTeX` and to test the possibilities, I decided to redo some of my old work., I don’t know how to transfer some elements to `LaTeX`, though.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Whenever there are such arrow diagrams (as in the 4th picture), you can usually convert the text part into a table, but I don’t know how to deal with the arrows. Perhaps a method of "hard inserting pictures", would help here.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Look around for Ti*k*Z and diagrams created with this package. There are *a lot* of examples on this site and on the internet already … Please try to come up with some code in order to make it easier to help you.

Comment: For chemical reactions, you could try the [`mhchem` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mhchem) and the [`chemfig` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemfig) of which the latter works nicely together with [PGF/Ti*k*Z](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) which you probably want to use for the basic diagram structure and arrows. For table-like structures you might want to look at the [`tikz-cd` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) which is an extension for Ti*k*Z.

Comment: @JasperHabicht thanks for pointing out the "tikz-cd" library, I also found the "forest" library. So I will try to make everything beautiful